# Lookup and replace a field and leave a 'Not Available' default output for unmatched records

Tags: ssis

Table 1 has field 'A'

Table 2 has fields 'B' and 'C'

Table 3 will receive an insert of fields 'A' and 'D', 'D' being generated from 'C' where 'A' matches 'B' or showing a 'Not Available' string for every record where 'A' does not have a matching 'B' field.

I am in fact trying to replicate a scribe DBLookupDefault behavior in SSIS but it's tricky to replicate this behavior within a single Data Flow.

Comment: To restate: Source data is T1.A and T1.D. Lookup is based on T1.A = T2.B. If found, replace T1.D pipeline value with T2.C. If nothing is found, replace text with `Not Available`

Comment: If I have the above correct, is there any value in ever pulling T1.D out of the source system? After the lookup, it's either N/A or T2.C

Comment: @billinkc T1.D will basically become a new field actually. I forgot to mention this. Before it's checked against T2, T1 will not have field 'D'.

Comment: @billinkc This is all before an insert into another table so basically field 'D' is part of a temp version of table 1 which will perform an insert into an unmentioned table 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this as a Lookup with the no match option set to Ignore Failure. If we make a match, we will add in the C column, aliased as D. Otherwise we'll have NULL

[image]

After the lookup, we want a Derived Column that checks the value of our newly minted D column. If it's NULL, then we'll patch in our unknown text. I'm lazy and used an SSIS Variable to do so. The expression you want is

```
ISNULL([D]) ? @[User::Lookup_Unknown] : [D]
```

Source query

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (10), (20), (30), (40))T1(A);
```

Lookup query

I intentionally exclude the 30 value. I also had to pad out my string to ensure I had room for my no-match text. I set the Derived column as Replace 'D'

```
SELECT B, CAST(C AS varchar(50)) AS C FROM (VALUES (10, 'Foo'), (20, 'Bar'), (40, 'Blee'))T2(B,C);
```

## Biml

Biml, the Business Intelligence Markup Language, describes the platform for business intelligence. Here, we're going to use it to describe the ETL. [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com), is a free add on for Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT that addresses a host of shortcomings with it. Here I'm using it to make a package that you can create in your own environment to compare with what you have done. You will need to update the third line there to point the Connection manager to a valid instance

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="CM_OLE" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package ConstraintMode="Linear" Name="so_29398714">
            <Variables>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="Lookup_Unknown">Not Available</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Lookup Ignore Failure">
                    <Transformations>
                        <!--
                        Simulate source table
                        -->
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="OLE_SRC">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT * FROM (VALUES (10), (20), (30), (40))T1(A);</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <!--
                        Lookup Important thing is to ignore failure
                        Here we exlude 30 from our sample data
                        Match based on T1.A to T2.B
                        -->
                        <Lookup Name="LKP Data" NoMatchBehavior="IgnoreFailure" OleDbConnectionName="CM_OLE">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT B, CAST(C AS varchar(50)) AS C FROM (VALUES (10, 'Foo'), (20, 'Bar'), (40, 'Blee'))T2(B,C);</DirectInput>
                            <Inputs>
                                <Column SourceColumn="A" TargetColumn="B" />
                            </Inputs>
                            <Outputs>
                                <Column SourceColumn="C" TargetColumn="D" />
                            </Outputs>
                        </Lookup>
                        <!--
                        Add derived column to handle the nulls for missed lookups
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Handle missed lookups">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column DataType="AnsiString" Name="D" ReplaceExisting="true">ISNULL([D]) ? @[User::Lookup_Unknown] : [D]</Column>
                            </Columns>
                        </DerivedColumns>
                        <!--
                        Add a placeholder for my data viewer
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Data Viewer Placeholder"></DerivedColumns>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```